Accessing Elements from Cameo Folder Using Velocity
I have a folder organized something like so:
Folder
Diagram
Block1
Block2
Subblock
Block3
I would like to create a foreach loop that only accesses the main blocks (eg block1, block2, block3).
My hope is for something that is generic and not getting all blocks then checking one by one if the names match the expected ones.
My thought is to somehow access Folder.inner_elements and then sort all the Class elements out (which is all the elements I desire), however my attempts so far have thrown errors.
Any ideas would be appreciated. I am new to both Velocity and Cameo, but I've tried looking through the documentation of both and don't see anything specific other than how to access all the blocks.
[edit]
I've been playing around with a couple ideas, but this is my current iteration:
Code:
#foreach($folder in $Package) 

#if($folder.name == “Folder_name”) 

#set($des_folder = $folder) 

#end 

#end 

#set($elements = $des_folder.inner_elements) 

#foreach($block in $elements) 

$block.name 

#end 

Error:
WARN: [Report] No such property: inner_elements of package on mr.inner_elements

Specify the errors you're encountering and provide a snippet of your current Velocity code.

Figured it out! For people's future reference I did the following:
#foreach($folder in $Package) 

#if($folder.name == “Folder_name”) 

#set($des_folder = $folder) 

#end 

#end 

#set($elements = $report.filterElement($report.getInnerElement($des_folder), [“Block”])) 

#foreach($block in $elements) 

$block.name 

#end 

Note that I tried $report.findElementInCollection($Package, "Folder_name") instead of the first foreach but it did not work for me - just created an empty document.
